# Execution of Parallel Script from a single Cron Job

Tags: shell-script, cron

How to execute a different `command/script` (Task-B) in a parallel mode, while the primary task `command/script` (Task-A) is exceeding the defined time window/period; which is mentioned in the `crontab` ?

@ Production environment, not having `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: A second line (with same numbers and stars) in your crontab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As l0b0 mentioned [in his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/368796/116858), the crontab file only specifies the start time of jobs. It doesn't care if the job takes hours to run and will happily start it again when the next start time arrives, even if the previous incarnation of the job is still running.

From your description, it sounds like you want task B to start if task A takes too long to run.

You may achieve this by combining the two tasks in one and the same script:

```
#!/bin/sh

timeout=600     # time before task B is started
lockfile=$(mktemp)
trap 'rm -f "$lockfile"' EXIT INT TERM QUIT

# Start task A
# A "lock file" is created to signal that the task is still running.
# It is deleted once the task has finished.

( touch "$lockfile" && start_task_A; rm -f "$lockfile" ) &
task_A_pid="$!"

sleep 1     # allow task A to start

# If task A started, sleep and then check whether the "lock file" exists.
if [ -f "$lockfile" ]; then
    sleep "$timeout"

    if [ -f "$lockfile" ]; then
        # This is task B.
        # In this case, task B's task is to kill task A (because it's
        # been running for too long).
        kill "$task_A_pid"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: If I need to execute the second script (as a task-b) to check some condition & status of task-a and if those things get matched as defined, then only it will kill the pid of `Task-A`........, how to make it that happen ?

Comment: @ShankarMajumder All of the test that you need to do should go into the above script before the `kill` (which kills task A). If you already have everything in a script, call that _instead of_ the `kill`.

Comment: Hi Kusalananda, I understood that but if I made an individual script for the `task-2`, then how it will capture the `Process ID` of `[task-1]` before killing, can you please share some guideline....?

Comment: @ShankarMajumder Start you task B script with `"$task_A_pid"` as a command line parameter. Thi PID of task A will then be available in the task B script as `$1` (if it's the first command line parameter).

Comment: You mean to say a variable `my $task_A_pid = "/path/to/task-a/script.sh";`.....?

Comment: @ShankarMajumder No. Call your task B script instead of the `kill` in my code with `task_B "$task_A_pid"` (change `task_B` to the name of your script).  Inside the task B script, use `kill "$1"` to kill task A. Is the B script a shell script?

Comment: Thanks Kusalananda, I got that. But what if I don't want to call that one and instead-of if I separately build it and make it execute from this way (crontab) `* * * * * /bin/timeout -h '{/path/to/task-b/script.sh}' 2 /path/to/task-a/script.sh`......?

Comment: @ShankarMajumder You can do it any way you want, Shankar. I just gave you an easy way to call a script after a timeout. If you have a better way of doing it, then go ahead. I don't knaw this `timeout ` utility that you use, so I can't comment on it.

Comment: Hello Kusalananda, if I want to capture `root` **pid@1234** `2769  0 13:53:10 pts/2    0:00 daemon_name` **Job/Script_Name** something else (_Job/Script Name_) along with the _PID_, then how is it possible ?

Comment: @ShankarMajumder This sounds like a new question to me.

Comment: No, I mean within the same script which you made.

Answer (score 3):

This will happen by default. Cron runs *all* the jobs which are scheduled for a given minute at approximately the same time. There's no queue, and there is definitely no time window/period. There is only a set of start times.

Comment: Which means it should be work `* * * * * /bin/timeout -h '{/path/to/task-b/script.sh}' 2 /path/to/task-a/script.sh`.....?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: It's just a `crontab` format,  I am just asking whether it will work or not.... ?

Comment: Have you tried it? In that case it should be a separate question.

Comment: No, before trying I just need to confirm whether the format (syntax) & logic is accurate or not ?